# Adjusting the line spacing of UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

How do I adjust the line height (line spacing) of a UITextView? Where do I change / add the code? I'm currently trying to add code to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in the AppDelegate.swift file. Here is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:     NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    return true
}
```

Then I select the UITextView and add User Defined Runtime Attributes of the following:

```
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 40
```

I already know I'm doing this completely wrong; how I could do it right?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are simply creating an empty paragraph style. Only the app delegate knows about it.

Instead, you should style your text in the class that manages the `UITextView` (there is no such thing as a <strike>`UITextLabel`</strike>). After you have obtained a reference to your text view you can do this:

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 40
let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: yourText, attributes:attributes)
```

You can also apply a style only to a specified portion (`NSRange`) of a text. But this is slightly more complicated, so you should ask another question here.

Comment: How would I 'obtain a reference to my text view' / 'style my text in the class that manages the UITextView?' (I'm brand new to this - thx)